# Conditional binomial problem

Tags: probability

An urn contains black balls and white balls.

We know that if we draw randomly with replacement, for example $N = 100$ balls, we have a probability greater than $P$ (example $P= 0.60$) to get more than $k$ (example $k = 33$) black balls.

What is the minimum initial percentage $R$ of the number of black balls contained in the urn by the total number of balls?

Is there an explicit formula $R(N, k, p)$ giving $R$ as a function of $N,\;k,$ and $p$?

Same questions if we perform the draw of the $N$ balls without replacement

Comment: The question seems not very well posed to me. The "probability greater than" bit should be "probability equal to". Further, the relation with the title is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw randomly with replacement $N$ balls and assume the probability of getting one black ball in one draw is $r$ then the probability of drawing at least $k$ black balls is $N$ draws is: $$P=\sum_{t=k}^{N}\left(\binom{N}{t}\cdot r^t \cdot (1-r)^{N-t}\right)$$
(You get it by setting $t$ to be the actual number of black balls you draw ($t\geq k$), choosing the $t$ appearances of the black balls, multiplying by the probabilities and dividing by total number of possibilities).
From here, for given $N,k,P$ you can find $r$, but it's not that nice and not explicit... :(

Comment: Are you sure about /2^N. It seems to me that we do not have to divide by 2^N .

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: Thanks, you are right